# Comparing escaped data with select box's unescaped value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html-entities

I have a page where I get select box options using an AJAX request, build a select box from that data, and then later use the selected value of the select box to get additional info from the response returned from the AJAX request (which is stored as a global variable).

Because I'm using `htmlentities()` to escape data before returning it from my PHP AJAX handler (which I should do to avoid XSS attacks, correct?), the indexes/property names in the returned data are escaped. So if the AJAX response object looks like this:

```
data:
{
    ...,
    Caf&eacute;: [...],
    ...
}
```

Then once I create a select box option from that data and get the select box's value at a later time, like this:

```
 $("#select").val();
```

The value retrieved from the select box is `Café`. This is a problem, because if I then try to get something from that index in `data`, like this:

```
data[$("#select").val()]
```

Then I get an error that the index is undefined, because the index isn't `Café`, it's `Caf&eacute;`.

What's the best way to solve the issue I'm having? It's possible that there might be a PHP solution, such as a way to not escape "safe" characters, or there might be a good JavaScript solution as well, so what's the best option?

**EDIT:** According to ZubaiR's comment, it's not necessary to escape data that's being returned from an AJAX handler as JSON, which means that should fix my problem. However, I've had this problem when not using AJAX (when echoing data directly to the page), so I'd like to find a solution for that case as well.

Comment: htmlentities are used to escape data for html. you do not need it if you output in json format. if you want to insert your json data in html page then you can escape data from javascript.

Comment: @ZubaiR That's really good to know, thank you! I've had this issue when echoing out JavaScript code, too, though, so I'll update my question to extend it to that situation.

Answer (score 0):

I did a little test for your case and produced some strange results

You can fint the test on [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/aHiKeHu/1/)

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="test_select">
    <option value="caf&eacute">caf&eacute (escaped value)</option>
    <option value="café">caf&eacute (not escaped value)</option>
</select>
<button id="test_button">Click to check my value from data</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = {"caf&eacute":1, "café":2};
    $(function () {
        $('#test_button').click(function() {
            alert(data[$('#test_select').val()]);
        })
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

for any select option I get "2" on jsbin. and on my local pc i get "undefined" for the first one and "2" for the second one.

So, to fix the problem you are having you need to use `café` as your option value (not escaped) and also do not escape js values